# Isthere any way to import excel data from sharepoint to SQLServer using ssis

Tags: sql-server, excel, file, sharepoint, load

How to import excel data from SharePoint site to SQL Serer Table using the CdataSharepoint component in ssis

I have tried to connect the SharePoint site using  the CDataSharePointSource component till connection manager getting success after that unbale to find the list of sheet

I am expecting how to use the CDataSharePointSource component to read the excel file from the sharepoint site